# Can someone lose all his reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, moderation

I came across a situation earlier this week where I got serial downvoted. I had a really good idea of who it was and the fact that he did this made me interested in his profile. At the moment of the serial voting, the guy had like 1k rep. Like two days after he had exactly 1 rep. His profile was still running and everything I can still see all his answer, but he has no more rep.

So, anyway I was wondering if it was all a coincidence or one can actually lose all his rep as a punishment? If it is, what kind of behavior can lead to that?

Comment: They were likely suspended. Is there a banner at the top of their profile page saying as much?

Comment: @MikeM. What do you mean by a banner ?

Comment: Oh damn yes, he has one! So when you get suspended you lose all your rep ?

Comment: Just until the suspension ends.

Comment: Oh I see thank you for your time ! But to answer my question, is it possible to lose it ?

Comment: [A Day in the Penalty Box](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) - Note _Your account will be locked at 1 reputation_

Comment: I don't think so, not like that, but I can't say authoritatively.

Comment: Oh well, thank you all, I learned something.

Comment: Just to note: I know of at least one user who (voluntarily) used up all their reputation on bounties. You don't just lose rep for "bad" reasons :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the sounds of it seems like the user has been [suspended](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/). Outside a suspension no, it's almost impossible to lose all your rep.

First off, you will always have at least 1 rep, even if you bounty all your rep away [the system will always make sure you have 1 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231809/250962).

It's not possible to downvote answers when you hit 1 rep because your [privilege for downvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) will be taken from you if you go below 125 rep.

It's possible to go down to one rep from just downvotes but given your confusion, I would assume the user has neutral or positively score posts and it wouldn't be normally possible to have neutral or positively score posts and 1 rep outside a suspension as

- +5 for Question Upvotes
- +10 for Answer Upvotes
- +15 for Accept Votes
- +2 for approved edits (before a threshold)
- -2 for downvotes
- -1 for downvoting answers (limited to, I think, 40 per day so -40)

You would need to be downvoted a lot more than you would need to be upvoted as such a user who continues to post negativity score posts can still have a good amount of rep (though by then they've probably been [banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) already).

I can imagine a situation where it would be possible for the rep to be high and then reduce down to 1 very quickly but it would involve the user giving away bounties and downvoting while being downvoted like mad. Such a situation would be very rare because of Voting Limits on users and it would need to be conspiracy level coordinated against the user.

So, in other words, it's actually impossible to lose all your rep because you will always have 1 and it's almost impossible to drop down to 1 rep ***if you're doing the right thing*** (bounties excluded)

Comment: Unless that user is also suddenly posting many spam/rude answers and be flagged, costing 100 reps for each post...